# Task "reminder" field and page layouts

Tags: page-layout, tasks

How can I configure the "reminder" field visibility in page layouts?

I can see the field at the bottom of the page, but it's not available in the "fields" section at the top of the page layouts. I would like to be able to add it or remove it to/from the layout.

For some reason, I cannot add images now. Will edit this later with the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (the same also applies for the recurrence section on a task).

There is an idea that's been open for 8 years asking for this -
 [Ability to reposition Reminder fields in Activity layouts](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BqQVAA0)

You can turn task reminders off globally for your organization in `Setup > Customize > Activities > Activity Settings` and uncheck `Enable Activity Reminders`

Comment: I assume that those fields will always show if reminders are on?